# What's wrong with my bmp imporer?

Tags: opengl, textures, bmp

So I kinda made a small bmp importer in order to be able to use texture in opengl but after I load the picture and stuff instead of a texture it just puts the color brown on the ... sqare 
I have also tried with more than 1 texture and i got the same resault.
Here's some code:

```
int LoadBitmap ( char *filename) {
  BITMAPFILEHEADER fileheader;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER fileinfo;
  RGBTRIPLE rgb;
  unsigned char *texture;
  FILE *f=fopen(filename,"r");
  num_texture++;
  fread(&fileheader,sizeof(fileheader),1,f);
  fread(&fileinfo,sizeof(fileinfo),1,f);
  cout<<fileinfo.biWidth<<" "<<fileinfo.biHeight<<endl;

  texture=new unsigned char[fileinfo.biWidth*fileinfo.biHeight*4];
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<fileinfo.biWidth*fileinfo.biHeight;i++)
  {
    fread(&rgb,sizeof(rgb),1,f);

    texture[j]=rgb.rgbtRed;
    texture[j+1]=rgb.rgbtGreen;
    texture[j+2]=rgb.rgbtBlue;
    texture[j+3]=255;
    j+=4;
  }
  fclose(f);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,num_texture);

  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);


  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,4,fileinfo.biWidth,fileinfo.biHeight,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture);
  gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,4,fileinfo.biWidth,fileinfo.biHeight,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture);

  delete[] texture;
  return num_texture;
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the drawing part:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
int a=LoadBitmap("texture1.bmp");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,a);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0,0);
  glVertex3f(-10,-10,0 );
  glTexCoord2f(0,1);
  glVertex3f(-10,10,0);
  glTexCoord2f(1,1);
  glVertex3f(10,10,0 );
  glTexCoord2f(1,0);
  glVertex3f(10,-10,0 );
 glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILE *f=fopen(filename,"r");
```

You may want to try opening the file in binary mode, it may simply be detecting an end of file, or otherwise mangling the input.

```
FILE *f=fopen(filename,"rb");
```

You also make some assumptions about the actual format of the file, but assuming you generated the BMPs yourself, I guess that might be ok.

Comment: Iv looked up bmp format before asking on : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format but sadly i don't know how to implement those things that are optimal ( i mean i don't really know how to pass them if they are not there) I would like to be able to import any bmp but im not sure how without the structure names to have some kind of headers or idk at the begging since they have variable sizes